# Can I set the condition to run if the earlier task has failed or been cancelled?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline that runs Cypress tests. When it is finished a `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` task runs that publishes screenshots of failed tests. Currently this is set to run with the `condition` set to `always()` in the yaml file.

This causes a problem when there are no failing tests and it causes the run to fail when all tests pass. I would like to set it so this tast only runs if the job fails or is cancelled. Is there a condition for this? Similar to `succeededOrFailed()`, maybe something like `canceledOrFailed()`.

Comment: Did you look at the available conditions? You can combine conditions with `or()` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel wrote you can use `or() expression in this way

```
or(canceled(), failed())
```

**Detailed answer**:
All tasks has general properties like `condition`

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  condition: <put condition here>
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

It allows you to control when given task should be executed. For this you can find here [Job status check functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-status-functions)

> You can use the following status check functions as expressions in conditions, but not in variable definitions.

Those functions (and `canceled` and `failed` are example of them) could be combined with logical [expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#functions). On that list you will find `or`.

So when you want to run given task only when pipeline was canceled or job failed

[image]

You should use expression `or(canceled(), failed())`

Comment: To make this more useful for less experienced, could you put a bit of context around it?

Comment: @AladinSpaz could you check if that version provide more value?